# React-Apollo - Query - renderProp: React warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using "Query" from "react-apollo" and my application returns me this error. I think I am understanding the problem: my application is trying to re-render a component which has been unmounted. I'm not sure how to solve that error. I've been reading the official documentation of Apollo and React but I still don't know how to fix.

Seems like othe user have the same problem than me: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3635

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in Query (at GetListOfUsers.js:19)
    in GetListOfUsers (at UserAdministration.js:11)
    in UserAdministration (at App.js:54)
```

This is my code:

```
// GetListOfUsers.js

import React from 'react'

import { ListOfUsers } from '../components/ListOfUsers'
import { Spinner } from '../components/Spinner'
import { ErrorAlert } from '../components/ErrorAlert'

import { Query } from 'react-apollo'

import { LIST_ALL_USERS } from '../gql/queries/users';

const renderProp = ( { loading, error, data } ) => {
    if (loading) return <Spinner key={'loading'} />
    if (error) return <ErrorAlert errorMessage={error.message} />

    return <ListOfUsers users={data.listAllUsers || []} />
}

export const GetListOfUsers = () => (
    <Query query={LIST_ALL_USERS} fetchPolicy="cache-and-network">
        {
            renderProp
        }
    </Query>
)
```

```
// ListOfUsers.js

import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import { parseUnixTimestamp } from '../../utils/utils'

export const ListOfUsers = ( { users = [] } ) => {
    return (
        <section className="table-responsive">
            <table className="table text-light">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Is administrator ?</th>
                        <th scope="col">Is active ?</th>
                        <th scope="col">Registration date</th>
                        <th scope="col">Last login</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        users.map(user => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={user.uuid}>
                                    <td>{user.email}</td>
                                    <td>{(user.isAdmin) ? 'yes': 'no'}</td>
                                    <td>{(user.isActive) ? 'yes': 'no'}</td>
                                    <td>{parseUnixTimestamp(user.registrationDate)}</td>
                                    <td>{parseUnixTimestamp(user.lastLogin)}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section>
    )
}


ListOfUsers.propTypes = {
    users: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
            email: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            uuid: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            isAdmin: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
            isActive: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
            registrationDate: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            lastLogin: PropTypes.string.isRequired
        })
    )
}
```

"GetListOfUsers" is called here:

```
// UserAdministration.js

import React, { Fragment } from 'react'

import { PageTitle } from '../components/PageTitle'

import { GetListOfUsers } from '../containers/GetListOfUsers'

const UserAdministration = () => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <PageTitle text='User administration panel' />
            <GetListOfUsers />
        </Fragment>
    )
}

UserAdministration.displayName = 'UserAdministration'

export default UserAdministration
```

I tried to modify the file "GetListOfUsers" to use "useQuery" and had the same problem. My code was like this:

```
// GetListOfUsers.js

import React from 'react'
import { useQuery } from 'react-apollo'

import { Spinner } from '../components/Spinner'
import { ErrorAlert } from '../components/ErrorAlert'
import { ListOfUsers } from '../components/ListOfUsers'

import { LIST_ALL_USERS } from '../gql/queries/users';

export const GetListOfUsers = () => {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(LIST_ALL_USERS);

    if (loading) return <Spinner />
    if (error) return <ErrorAlert errorMessage={error.message} />

    return <ListOfUsers users={data.listAllUsers || []} />
}
```

Comment: in first look it seems you need to renderProp() instead renderProp, or write <renderProp/> because of it is a react component function.

Comment: It seems It is better to use Apollo-hooks when you are using react component functions.
Personally i use ```withApollo``` to access client directly in class components, or using ```useApolloClient``` hook in functional components.

Comment: but there is useQuery and useLazyQuery , .... in apollo-hooks. My personal opinion about your main question is you are using Query component in a functional component, change it to ```useQuery``` hook and see the result.

Comment: Could you show me an example, please? I am not an expert in React or Apollo

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/

Comment: See this example. if it can't help you tell me to send another

Comment: I just updated the question with a possible implementation of "useQuery", however this gives me other problems as detailed in the question.

Comment: import useQuery from hooks not react-apollo, here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apollo/react-hooks

Comment: And how GetListOfUsers called?

Comment: I can't see any more problem, May there is something force render components. Also you can use ```useLazyQuery```and trigger the query in ```useEffect()``` with empty array as second arg. It means ```componentDidMount```. write a console.warn there and see how many times your component mounting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found two solutions to my case:

1. Remove the `fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'` (maybe not what you want)

OR

2. Upgrade Apollo to the new v3.0 (still in beta when this answer was written)

Both options fixed the warning to me.

Comment: No, the error still appears will strict mode, I have been trying to fix since last 4 days, Now I got what is causing the problem, it's because of strict mode https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3635